# how to solve this driver error in jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automation

I have an automation project in Java + Selenium that we run at the company every Tuesday and Thursday on Jenkins. It is a project that uses the Chrome driver, and of the 600 scenarios it has, some have failed, being reported on the reportportal as ignored.

When looking at the jenkins log, all these "ignored" have an error line (in addition to all the others, but this always appears in all ignored)

`net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver`

This has caused several scenarios to fail, as it is ignored in the first outline and the other examples are not executed. What should execute 550 successful scenarios on average out of 600, is failing more than 140, of which 140, at least 80 with this status, of ignored

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5rWK.png)

[ignored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D7eT.png)

```
`<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
<artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
<version>2.0.39</version>
<scope>test</scope>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
<artifactId>serenity-cucumber4</artifactId>
<version>1.0.5</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
<version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.epam.reportportal</groupId>
<artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
<version>4.0.19</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.invictum</groupId>
<artifactId>serenity-reportportal-integration</artifactId>
<version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
<version>2.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
<artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
<version>1.18.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
<version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.lookfirst</groupId>
<artifactId>sardine</artifactId>
<version>5.9</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>`
```